Arcgis online not reading link
Arcgis online is not reading geoserver link. I have no experience in the area, and I need to know if I'm doing something wrong.
I was able to read the link in Qgis normally. https://geoserver.iocasta.com.br/geoserver/source/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=source%3Ageo_pol_terras_indiginas&bbox=-73.72518920898438%2C-31.20516014099121%2C-34.92895507 8125%2C5.272125244140625&width=768&height=722&srs =EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application%2Fatom%20xml
